# Select dates based on mask

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Please see the following dataframe:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = {'Sample': {1: 'XXXXX123456',
2: 'XXXXX12345',
3: 'XXX1234568',
4: 'XXX1234569',
5: 'XXX12345456'},
'sample_received': {1: Timestamp('2022-08-11 14:24:17'),
2: 'NaT',
3: Timestamp('2022-08-12 13:17:24'),
4: Timestamp('2022-09-12 13:17:22'),
5: Timestamp('2022-08-13 15:17:35')},
'result_received': {1: Timestamp('2022-08-18 00:00:00'),
2: Timestamp('2022-08-15 00:00:00'),
3: Timestamp('2022-08-17 00:00:00'),
4: Timestamp('2022-08-13 00:00:00'),
5: Timestamp('2022-08-13 00:00:00')}}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

I would like to count all the rows that are in a certain column of the dataframe (this includes NaT values).

Lets say in the above df that i want to count all dates in the 'sample_received' column that are at least 2022-08-12 and all the dates in the 'result_received' column that are under 14.

The code that I use for this is the following:

```
df['sample_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sample_received'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
df['sample_received'] = df['sample_received'].dt.date
df['sample_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sample_received'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
df['result_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['result_received'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
df['result_received'] = df['result_received'].dt.date
df['result_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['result_received'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
end_date = '2022-08-14'
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
mask_result_received_1_14_aug = (df['result_received'] <= end_date)
df['result_received'].loc[mask_result_received_1_14_aug]
```

This all luckly works completely fine, I know that I did not apply the len() function to count the rows.

However, when I want to count the number of rows in the sample_received column, there happens something in the calculation:

```
df['sample_received'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sample_received'], format="%Y/%m/%d")
df['sample_received'] = df['sample_received'].dt.date
start_date = '2022-08-01'
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date, format="%Y/%m/%d")
mask_sample_received_1_14_aug = (df['sample_received'] <= start_date)
df['sample_received'].loc[mask_sample_received_1_14_aug]
```

Somehow, it already takes the calculations of the result_received calculations into account.

Does someone know how this can be adjusted?

Kind regards : )

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question correctly, after all the code, you just want to count the number of rows in the dataframe.

that being the case, you just need to do this:

```
df.count()
```

Which returns this:

```
Sample             5
sample_received    4
result_received    5
dtype: int64
```

And the count of `result_received` would specifically be:

```py
r = df.count()[2]
print('results received:', r)
```

Which returns this:

```
results received: 5
```